# Zoom in & zoom out in Angular not working for ngx-image-cropper

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, ngx-image-cropper

I am trying for Zoom in & Zoom out from ngx-image-cropper. I am not getting any error but when I click the button zoomOut or ZoomIn it's not working.

What am I doing wrong here?

My TS code

```
  zoomOut() {
    this.scale -= .1;
    this.transform = {
        ...this.transform,
        scale: this.scale
    };
}

zoomIn() {
    this.scale += .1;
    this.transform = {
        ...this.transform,
        scale: this.scale
    };
}
```

My HTML code

```
       <button class="btn zoomIn" (click)="zoomIn()" tooltip="Zoom In" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Zoom In"></button>
       <button class="btn zoomOut" (click)="zoomOut()" tooltip="Zoom Out" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Zoom Out"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
export class AppComponent {  
  zoom:boolean=false;
  zoomOut(){
    this.zoom=false;
  }
  zoomIn(){
    
    this.zoom=true;
  }
  getheight(){
    if(this.zoom==true){
      return '500px';
      //return your desiderd value in pixel or in percentage
    }
    else{
      return '200px';
      }
  }

}
```

```css
button{
    padding: 8px;
}
#test-zoom{
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
}
.zoom-card{
    height: 500px;
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    background: lime;
}

.test-image{
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="test-zoom">
  <div class="zoom-card">
    <img [ngStyle]="{'height':getheight()}" width="auto" class="test-image" src="https://www.netcetra.com/images/howto_images/photoshop-logo.jpg">
    <br>
    <button (click)="zoomIn()" >Zoom In</button>
    <button (click)="zoomOut()" >Zoom Out</button>

  </div>
</section>
```

Use this code and paste it into app.component.ts, CSS, and HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to this [another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66016717/image-change-greyscale-slider-in-angular/66017046?noredirect=1#comment116734266_66017046). Well, really Angular is the same always, relationate variables in .ts (the model) with the .html (the view). Well in the docs [about binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding) the e.g. is very poor. Personally I hate the example `{{variable}}` :)

You declare a variable scale

```
scale:number=1;

<!--see that you can use the .html to makes "simple code"
     (equal a variable to another an so on)
-->
<button class="btn zoomIn" (click)="scale=scale+.1"></button>
<button class="btn zoomIn" (click)="scale=scale-.1"></button>

<img [style.transform]="'scale('+scale+')'" ...>
```

Comment: i tried your code in my page the zoom is not happening the similar way for greyscale and sepia etc.,

But the slider is working.

I am not getting any error getting only warning Please help me