# Image change greyscale (Slider) in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am trying to change image into Greyscale and Sepia using slider control

Here is my html code

```
       <div class="card-body">
        <input id="sepia" type="range" oninput="set(this, 'sepia');" value="0" step="0.1" min="0" max="1"> Sepia <span id="Amount_sepia">(0)</span><br/>
        <input id="grayscale" type="range" oninput="set(this, 'grayscale');" value="0" step="0.1" min="0" max="1"> Grayscale <span id="Amount_grayscale">(0)</span><br/>
      </div>

              <img class="img-fluid" id="img_prev" src="{{actualImage}}" *ngIf="!this.showCropper" />
                <image-cropper id="img_prev"  class="imageclass" *ngIf="this.showCropper" 
                        [autoCrop]="false"
                          [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent"
                           [maintainAspectRatio]="true"
                           [aspectRatio]="4 / 3"
                           [resizeToWidth]="256"
                           [cropperMinWidth]="128"
                            [onlyScaleDown]="true"
                           format="png"
                           (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)"
                           (imageLoaded)="imageLoaded()"
                           (cropperReady)="cropperReady()"
                           (loadImageFailed)="loadImageFailed()" style="max-height:500px"> 
                </image-cropper>
```

Here is my ts for the same

```
public set(e,f){
    document.getElementById('img_prev').style["filter"] = f+"("+e.value+")";
    document.getElementById('Amount_'+f).innerHTML="("+e.value+")";
 }
```

I am getting error

```
(index):13 Uncaught ReferenceError: set is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.oninput ((index):13)
```

Comment: set is a reserved word in javascript. You can’t use it as a function name..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use an  "Angular way"?

You declare two variables

```
  sepia=0;
  grayScale=0;
```

And simply use `[(ngModel)]` and `[style.filter]`

```
<input id="sepia" type="range" [(ngModel)]="sepia" 
    step="0.1" min="0" max="1"> Sepia
    <span id="Amount_sepia">({{sepia}})</span>
<br/>
<input id="grayscale" type="range" [(ngModel)]="grayScale" 
    step="0.1" min="0" max="1"> Grayscale
<span id="Amount_grayscale">({{grayScale}})</span>
<br/>
<img [style.filter]="'grayscale('+grayScale+') sepia('+sepia+')'" 
    src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=1">
```

See [simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hot2sl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: thank you so much for the effort but when i click the stackblitz I was not able to see the output could you please help me  on that

Comment: for me the links work, BTW you simple create a component, in .ts you write the two variables -after the `export class AppComponent  { ...here..}` and in the .html copy and paste the html code. A [(ngModel)] makes that the "variable" get the value of the slider. When you use [style.filter]="....", the expresion under the quotes must return a string, e.g. `"grayscale(.3) sepia(0)"` -the only is get attention with the quotes and parenthesis-. Think that Angular relationate the variables in .ts with the .html, when a variable change, the .html is repainted with the new values.

Comment: Thank you so much 

Could you please help me on this question also 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65998334/zoom-in-zoom-out-angular-not-working-for-ngx-image-cropper

Comment: @Elliseo I have applied the same code in my page the image nothing changed there 

<img class="img-fluid" style="border:1px solid red" [style.filter]="'grayscale('+grayScale+') sepia('+sepia+') hue-rotate('+hueRotate+'deg) saturate('+saturate+')'"  id="img_prev" src="{{actualImage}}" *ngIf="!this.showCropper" />

Comment: this is my ts

  sepia=0;
  grayScale=0;
  hueRotate=0;
  saturate=1;

Answer (score 0):

In the above example `oninput` attribute is used which is a [global event attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp). This is usually used with vanilla js but in Angular there is an other approach to call function in the TypeScript code: the event binding.

In Angular the global event attributes are not used, instead of them we bind to the [DOM Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) with the event binding feature of Angular.

It follows `oninput="set(this, 'sepia');"` should be changed to a format with `(input)="set(..params..)"`.

However, some adaptation seems to be necessary. For example the `this` as parameter in input binding won't work,  most probably the `$event` will contain the necessary information. On the other hand it is not recommended to access native DOM Elements using `document.getElementById`, I recommend to use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) instead of it.